# Blank (background) screen after login

Tags: windows-xp

I'm having a weird issue where if I login as any user (admin, end user, domain admin) onto this one XP workstation, it shows the background screen for quite sometime before explorer actually comes up.  I've found that killing the svchost.exe associated with RPC will finally cause windows to come up.  If I login to safe mode, it does not have this issue.

I'm also seeing some DCOM errors in the event log:
The server  did not register with DCOM within the required timeout

I'm about ready to re-ghost this machine as I have no clue what else to do, but I heard about something very similar happening on another workstation yesterday... so I'd really like to resolve this.

Comment: funny, i've been seeing the same thing.  my network server was down for a bit and i had mapped drives that were down, i assumed that was the cause.  but all the drives are back up now and i'm still seeing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm I would try a system restore back to when it was working okay last and/or a repair installation next.  Although, this would probably take the same amount of time, if not more, than to re-ghost it.

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot to mention I tried a system restore to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

If re-ghosting doesn't work, maybe this machine has a bad peripheral device that gets stuck during boot. In this case, better check internal cables and try to reboot with as many peripherals disconnected as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you have network drive mappings check to see that all of the shares that they are mapping to a) exist and b) are reachable.  If not, try disconnecting the bad ones and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: that's what i assumed was causing my issue, but my mappings are fixed now.  don't think that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try disabling the Windows Image Acquisition service in your services manager (and unplug all of your peripheral devices) to see if that helps.

Comment: what makes you say that?  (just curious, it's a pretty minimal answer.)

Comment: I suggested to try that because I've had problems in the past with certain devices that use the Windows Image Acquisition service causing Windows Explorer to hang. The service isn't really needed in a lot of situations (including most server setups). Usually when you open My Computer is when you see the issue (you'll see a little flash light go back and forth usually). Also, in addition to this suggestion, I would make sure to turn off "Automatically search for network folders and printers" from the "View" tab in your Folder Options.